# Magento1 SUPEE-11086 Potential Issues?

Tags: magento-1, security, patches, supee-11086

The Description of the patch [SUPEE-11086](https://magento.com/security/patches/supee-11086) is:

> SUPEE-11086, Magento Commerce 1.14.4.1 and Open Source 1.9.4.1 contain
>   multiple security enhancements that help close remote code execution
>   (RCE), cross-site scripting (XSS), cross-site request forgery (CSRF)
>   and other vulnerabilities.

Also includes patch for SQL Injection with CVSSv3 Severity: 9.0

> An unauthenticated user can execute arbitrary code through an SQL
>   injection vulnerability, which causes sensitive data leakage.

Are there any issues or problems we can expect from this patch?

Comment: @Amit my question is specific for magento1. The other question is for both versions (m1 and m2). You also commented on the other question that he should make different questions for m1 and m2

Answer (score 1):

The following files are added or amended (in the 1.9.4.0 version of the patch, there may be more in older M1 versions):

```
app/Mage.php
app/code/core/Mage/Admin/Model/Session.php
app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Api/Buttons.php
app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Catalog/Product/Edit.php
app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Customer/Group/Edit.php
app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Permissions/Buttons.php
app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/System/Design/Edit.php
app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/System/Store/Edit.php
app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Controller/Action.php
app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Helper/Data.php
app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Model/Email/PathValidator.php
app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Model/LayoutUpdate/Validator.php
app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Model/System/Config/Backend/Gatewayurl.php
app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Model/System/Config/Backend/Protected.php
app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Api/RoleController.php
app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Api/UserController.php
app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Catalog/Product/Action/AttributeController.php
app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Catalog/Product/AttributeController.php
app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Catalog/Product/WidgetController.php
app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Catalog/ProductController.php
app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Cms/WysiwygController.php
app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/CustomerController.php
app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Permissions/RoleController.php
app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Permissions/UserController.php
app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Promo/CatalogController.php
app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Promo/QuoteController.php
app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/System/BackupController.php
app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/System/DesignController.php
app/code/core/Mage/Api2/Block/Adminhtml/Roles/Buttons.php
app/code/core/Mage/Api2/controllers/Adminhtml/Api2/AttributeController.php
app/code/core/Mage/Api2/controllers/Adminhtml/Api2/RoleController.php
app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Product/Option/Type/Select.php
app/code/core/Mage/Cms/Helper/Data.php
app/code/core/Mage/Cms/etc/config.xml
app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php
app/code/core/Mage/Core/Helper/Abstract.php
app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/File/Validator/StreamWrapper.php
app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Input/Filter/MaliciousCode.php
app/code/core/Mage/Core/etc/system.xml
app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Attribute/Data/File.php
app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Attribute/Abstract.php
app/code/core/Mage/Oauth/controllers/Adminhtml/Oauth/ConsumerController.php
app/code/core/Mage/Rss/etc/system.xml
app/code/core/Mage/Usa/etc/system.xml
app/code/core/Mage/Widget/controllers/Adminhtml/Widget/InstanceController.php
app/etc/config.xml
app/locale/en_US/Mage_Adminhtml.csv
app/locale/en_US/Mage_Core.csv
app/locale/en_US/Mage_Rss.csv
app/locale/en_US/Mage_Widget.csv
lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php
lib/Varien/Filter/Template.php
```